# casting exception

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

```
Set cust = customer.getCustomerBills();
Iterator<Customer> seriter = (Iterator)cust;
```

I am facing a casting exception when I iterate on Set.

Exception is: `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to java.util.Iterator`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You don't cast a collection to `Iterator`. You obtain one: `cust.iterator()`:

```
Set<Customer> cust = customer.getCustomerBills();
Iterator<Customer> seriter = cust.iterator();
```

(A `Collection` is [`Iterable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which defines the `iterator()` method.)

Answer (score 0):

Iterator seriter = (Iterator)cust;
is not a proper casting so an exception is being thrown.

use Iterator seriter = cust.iterator();